# Is there a way to override default functions in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

So what I want to do is make `findOne` work more like it does in Meteor, but through the Mongo shell. In short I want to be able to do something like this `db.collection.findOne("thisIsAnId")` and have it lookup that id in that collection.

I tried loading a file that has this in it...

```
db.collection.findOne = function(query, fields, options){
    if(typeof query === "string") {
        return db.collection.originalFindOne({_id : query}, fields, options);
    }

    return db.collection.originalFindOne(query, fields, options); 
}
```

Where `originalFindOne` would just chain to the default `findOne`, this didn't work at all. So after having no luck finding a way to override a default function I thought maybe I could create a new function like `db.collection.simpleFindOne()` or something, but I can't find a way to attach it to the mongo shell so that it will be available to any collection.

Anyone have some insight on how mongo internals work that could give me some help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this snippet to one of your Mongo config files:

```
(function() {

// Duck-punch Mongo's `findOne` to work like Meteor's `findOne`
if (
  typeof DBCollection !== "undefined" && DBCollection &&
  DBCollection.prototype && typeof DBCollection.prototype.findOne === "function" &&
  typeof ObjectId !== "undefined" && ObjectId
) {
  var _findOne = DBCollection.prototype.findOne,
      _slice = Array.prototype.slice;
  DBCollection.prototype.findOne = function() {
    var args = _slice.call(arguments);
    if (args.length > 0 && (typeof args[0] === "string" || args[0] instanceof ObjectId)) {
      args[0] = { _id: args[0] };
    }
    return _findOne.apply(this, args);
  };
}

})();
```

I originally found the `DBCollection` object/class by typing `db.myCollection.constructor` into the Mongo shell. I then confirmed that `findOne` was defined on its prototype by verifying that (a) `DBCollection` was globally accessible, (b) that `DBCollection.prototype` existed, and (c) that `typeof DBCollection.prototype.findOne === "function"` (much like the snippet does).

---

**Edit:** Added a logic branch to also cover ObjectId-based IDs.